# Multiple join query to exclude certain records

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have 3 models:

```
class SocialAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_social_accounts
  has_many :messages, through: :message_social_accounts
end

class MessageSocialAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :social_account
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :message_social_accounts
 has_many :social_accounts, through: :message_social_accounts
end
```

Having a number of specific social accounts I am trying to establish which ones of these did not receive a message yet.
I am trying to create a join query to find social accounts from the database:
a) that have ids in [1..20] and
b) that have dont have any message_social_account records with message id = 1

Tried this join:

```
SocialAccount.select('social_accounts.*').joins(:message_social_accounts).group('social_accounts.id').where("social_accounts.id IN (#{potential_recipients.map{|x|x.id}.join(',')}) AND message_social_accounts.message_id IS NOT #{self.id}").to_a
```

but it hasn't returned the desired result. Can clues? Thanks

**EDIT**

The following query was created as a result:

```
"SELECT social_accounts.* FROM \"social_accounts\" INNER JOIN \"message_social_accounts\" ON \"message_social_accounts\".\"social_account_id\" = \"social_accounts\".\"id\" WHERE (social_accounts.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) AND message_social_accounts.message_id IS NOT 1) GROUP BY social_accounts.id"
```

**EDIT2**
example of message_social_account records

```
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 4, message_id: 4, social_account_id: 4, read_time: "2000-01-01 12:06:40", created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 5, message_id: 5, social_account_id: 3, read_time: "2000-01-01 11:34:34", created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 6, message_id: 6, social_account_id: 2, read_time: "2000-01-01 02:13:25", created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 33, message_id: 33, social_account_id: 3, read_time: "2000-01-01 13:40:21", created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 36, message_id: 36, social_account_id: 4, read_time: nil, created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 37, message_id: 37, social_account_id: 2, read_time: nil, created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 42, message_id: 42, social_account_id: 3, read_time: "2000-01-01 09:32:45", created_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", updated_at: "2015-02-20 20:43:46", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 44, message_id: 45, social_account_id: 1, read_time: nil, created_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:31", updated_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:40", push_notification: true>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 45, message_id: 45, social_account_id: 2, read_time: nil, created_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:31", updated_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:31", push_notification: nil>,
#<MessageSocialAccount id: 46, message_id: 45, social_account_id: 3, read_time: nil, created_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:31", updated_at: "2015-03-02 16:07:31", push_notification: nil>
```

Comment: Hi , evuo , can you please write your SQL Query so that we can make it into ruby on rails syntax?

Comment: could you explain one more time what is this list `social_accounts.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)` stands for?

Comment: Those are ids of the social accounts that I have already filtered out in previous queries. So I only want to select social accounts with one of those ids.

Comment: ok. we have `message_social_accounts.message_id IS NOT 1` then. what do you mean by this? usually `message_social_accounts.message_id` means table `message`.`id` foreign key, and `message`.`id` is unique. so you must have just one record with `id`=1. what is the logic you are trying to apply using this clause?

Comment: For every message sent to a social account there is a record in the message_social_accounts table. So I am trying to exclude all the social accounts that have a message_social_account record for the specific message (here with an id =1). I tried also something along the lines `where count( select id from message_social_accounts where message_social_accounts.message_id=1) =0` but that was not correct neither.

Comment: I am still confusing. Could you provide sample of data from your `message_social_accounts`? 10-20 rows? and expected result for that set of rows

Comment: @evoo so you want all these records to be present in result? because no one of them has message_id=1 and all social_account_id  in your list?

Comment: This is just a sample from my local database, I am testing with rspec so those results would be different.

Comment: I understand that it is a sample. my question is: if this is the sample of data - what the expected result you need? post the expected result rows based on this source data please